# How do I set the homepage to the WordPress Admin Dashboard login?

Tags: wp-admin, admin, login, dashboard, homepage

I'm looking for a solution to set my [WordPress login page](https://wordpress.org/support/article/dashboard-screen/) as the homepage. Maybe a redirect 301 will work. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Just create a login form in frontend home page

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Custom default index page
DirectoryIndex ./wp-login.php
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Comment the last line and just add this line to index.php file

```
    require __DIR__ . '/wp-login.php';
```

Means, it will look like this

```
    ........
    #require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
    require __DIR__ . '/wp-login.php';
```